# render html elements to react as valid react form element that can be submitted

Tags: reactjs

I know someone may say this is duplicate but it is not, just see my problem first please,

I was working with django polymorphic model where I have to give a user a form depending on the choices the made on previous steps of the posting process on the kind of things they want to post, so making this thousands of forms in react frontend would give me other millions of jobs both in the react frontend and django backend.

so I had to make django render its model forms then I serialized the outputted HTML content and pushed it to react frontend, however consuming the HTML in react has turned out to be an issue now since the form can be shown correctly but submitting the form, the dangerous rendered HTML form fields are not captured, my big questiong actually is, is there a way the I can read the form elements,

I have tries this two code but both give same result

```
<form onSubmit={this.PostProduct} method='post'>
    <input name={"just_see"}/> // accessing this form field is possible coz it is react compenent
  { ReactHtmlParser(this.state.form) } // cannot access form field here
<button>submit<button>
<form>
```

again this one works just as the above one

```
<input name={"just_see"}/>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.form}}/>
```

Will appreciate if someone know what I can do please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a ref and then navigate to the DOM elements:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
onClick() {
    e.preventDefault();
    let myform= this.myRef.current
    let inputs_ = myform.querySelectorAll('input')
    var data = {}
    let index = 0
    for (let entry of inputs_) {
        data[entry.name] = entry.value
        index += 1
    }
    console.log(data)
}
render() {
    return <div ref={myRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.form}}/>
}
```

Comment: le me try will get back to you

Comment: just saved my day... how better could a correct answer look like? thanks it worked!!

Comment: aha - glad to have helped!!